# Hazelcast - distributed data structure state of other members / monitoring consistency corruption

Tags: hazelcast, distributed-caching, hazelcast-imap, jcache

I have a distributed `IMap` (exposed through a `JCache` implementation). When I access it, I get the data of the requesting member. I wish to see the state of this dataset in other members in order to debug consistency corruption scenarios such as stale data in one of the nodes, and so on.

I would also like to explore other recommended practices to monitor the data consistency across the cluster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A runnable/callable that is `HazelcastInstanceAware` can invoke [localKeySet()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html#localKeySet--). This would give it access to the subset of keys stored on each node.

If `read-from-backup` is enabled, when that same runnable retrieves the value, it gets the value stored on that node.

[This](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/consistency-and-replication/replication-algorithm) might also be a useful read.